# Is there a way to change date from another struct using CalendarKit?

Tags: calendarkit

I'm using CalendarKit and SwiftUI. I need to create "Today" button and Date Picker to select date, but I didn't foudn any solution, so is there a way to change the date or call somethign like move(to date: Date) function from another view?

Comment: What have you tried? A minimal reproducible product will get you better answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I don't think an example is needed. This is a question for the CalendarKit library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I suggest you coding your "change date" logic in UIKit for now and then exposing the CalendarKit to SwiftUI as explained in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64432749/can-i-use-view-controller-calendarkit-in-swiftui-application

This is until CalendarKit gets full SwiftUI support.

Richard, CalendarKit creator

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I'm using

```
var customDayView: DayView?


class CustomCalendarExampleController: DayViewController {
  ....
   
    override func loadView() {
        .....
        customDayView = dayView
        ...
    }
}


func moveDate(_ date: Date) {
        let offsetDate = dateOnly(date: date, calendar: customDayView!.calendar)
        customDayView!.state?.move(to: offsetDate)
    }
```

Comment: Looks good, but why do you keep the `customDayView` outside of the `CustomCalendarExampleController`? You can just tie it's lifecycle to that of VC and create it in the `loadView ` method